# View is onscreen but self.view.window is still nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController, let's say `FooViewController` and it has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSAttributedString *foo;
```

I want to update the UI when the view appears, so the `viewDidLoad` and foo's `setter` is like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.foo = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]} ];
}

- (void)setFoo:(NSAttributedString *)foo
{
    _foo = foo;
    if (self.view.window) [self updateUI];
}
```

I expected `updateUI` method would be called when the view is onscreen, but it didn't. Only when I remove `if (self.view.window)`, the method is called. What's the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the code to `viewDidAppear` (or just the bit that calls `[self updateUI]`).

*Loading* merely means it's been deserialized from the NIB, while *appearing* means it's part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: You mean viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanks. And you `moved` really fast ;)